# What BST method is this, and what is the output?

Tags: binary-search-tree

I was trying to better my understanding of BST and came across this problem. Maybe it's late and my brain isn't functioning but I cant seem to figure it out.

What is the output of the method call x.someMethod(9)? (x is the BinTreeNode depicted below.)

```
public int someMethod(int k) {

  if (k > size() || k < 1)
    return -1;

  int x = 0;
  if (left != null) 
    x = left.size();

  if (k <= x)
    return left.someMethod(k);
  else if (k - x == 1)
    return data;
  else
    return right.someMethod(k-x-1);

}
                       x→10
                      /    \
                    5       15
                  /   \        \    
                2     7          20
              /      /  \       /  \
            1      6     9     18  35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someMethod(k) outputs the value of kth smallest number stored in the BST.

Termination is straight forward.
The code recursively selects left subtree or right depending on number of nodes in left subtree and k.

Answer is 20 in the above case.